# Is it ok to temporarily store password in session variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to implement a multistep form in rails using Devise.  I plan on storing the information in session variables to persist from one step to the next.  My question is, is it ok to store the password in plain text in a session variable and then clear it once done with the form?

Comment: its definitely not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on security but my intuition told me this is not a good solution though possible.

A better solution is:

In step 1, you create the user actually and save the passwords, email as usual.

In step 2 or more, you update this user's record in db with further input. If anything not satisfied you can even delete this user finally.

This is based on convention and is better than hack.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not.  If you read the rails guide, there is a specific bullet point about this:

> The client can see everything you store in a session, because it is stored in clear-text (actually Base64-encoded, so not encrypted). So, of course, you don’t want to store any secrets here. To prevent session hash tampering, a digest is calculated from the session with a server-side secret and inserted into the end of the cookie.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/security.html#session-storage